# Why is BountyAmount for votetypeid = 8 empty in the votes table of MathOverflow

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer, mathoverflow

While helping out on a SEDE query [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7436532#7436532) I was looking at the votes table in the MathOveflow database, specially the records for votetypeid = 8.

I [noticed](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/946728) that the bountyamount isn't present in these rows prior to 25 june 2013. I presume this correlates to the [join date of MathOverflow as an SE 2.0 site to the network](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/754/46099).

Strangely enough the [votes.votetypeid = 9 (BountyClose)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) does have a populated BountyAmount field prior to 25 june 2013 so it doesn't look like this data was missing.

Is this a data import issue and can this be repaired? If this can't be repaired I would appreciate to learn how I can reconstruct the bountyamount for a BountyStart, specially when there is no winner or when only half of the bounty is awarded.